# Java: How do I simulate probability?

Tags: java, probability

I have a set of over 100 different probabilities ranging from 0.007379 all the way to 0.913855 (These probabilities were collected from an actuary table http://www.ssa.gov/oact/STATS/table4c6.html).  In Java, how can I use these probabilities to determine whether something will happen or not?  Something along these lines...

```
public boolean prob(double probability){
  if (you get lucky)
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `if (expression) return true; else return false;` just use `return expression;`.

Comment: I'd be willing to guess that those values fall in a standard 'bell curve' like measuring IQ, or weight, or height.  As such, a completely random number between 0 and 1 will not produce the same curve (with enough iterations, it should form a relatively flat line).

Comment: These values represent the probability of dying within a year at each age from 0 to 119.  Not a bell curve!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Random` class allows you to create a consistent set of random numbers so that every time you run the program, the same sequence of values is generated. You can also generate normally distributed random values with the Random class. I doubt you need any of that.

For what you describe, I would just use Math.random. So, given the age of a man we could write something like:

```
double prob = manDeathTable[age];
if( Math.random() < prob )
   virtualManDiesThisYear();
```

Answer (score 6):

First you need to create an instance of [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) somewhere sensible in your program - for example when your program starts.

```
Random random = new Random();
```

Use this code to see whether an event happens:

```
boolean happens = random.NextDouble() < prob;
```

Comment: Does random.NextDouble() generate a number as small as .0007?

Comment: @AdamSoffer Indeed, it will generate a number that small about 0.07% of the time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where that range came from.  If you have a distribution in mind, I'd recommend using a Random to generate a value and get on with it.

```
public ProbabilityGenerator {
    private double [] yourValuesHere = {  0.007379, 0.5,  0.913855 };
    private Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    public synchronized double getProbability() {
        return this.yourValuesHere[this.random.nextInt(yourValuesHere.length));
    }
}
```